# Get a list of autocad layers with edzxf

Tags: python, autocad, ezdxf

I want to get a list of autocad layer names with `ezdxf`.

I have referenced the `ezdxf` documentation but I do not know how.

The following is described in the documentation, do you use this?

> `Drawing.layout_names()`
>   　 Get a list of available paper space layouts.

Please tell me an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a very basic example:

```
import ezdxf

dwg = ezdxf.new()
for layer in dwg.layers:
    print layer.dxf.name
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was able to solve it safely.